# what is the purpose of mail.smtp.auth.ntlm.domain property in java mail properties

Tags: java, jakarta-mail, exchange-server

I am configuring MS Exchange Server 2007 for the first time. Although I have configured it successfully. I just want to know about the property **mail.smtp.auth.ntlm.domain**. One of my client has asked about this property.

I am able to connect to MS Exchange Server without setting this property. Then what is the purpose of this property at all. In which case, this property is required? Please give me some pointers, so that I can move in the right direction.

Answer (score 2):

It's part of the NTLM authentication protocol.  If you specify the username as domain\user, you don't need to specify this property.

Comment: Thanks Bill. But I am able to authenticate by setting the username as exchange server user and without specifying that property.

Comment: I'm not an Exchange expert. Perhaps Exchange provides an appropriate default value in some cases?